# Should I put a string variable in quotes or use the concatenation operator when dealing with strings in php?

Tags: php, string, coding-style

I am trying to output a string, but I'm not sure coding convention wise how I should write my code.

From my understanding these two produce similar results, but are syntactically different. Is there any improvement to readability one way or the other?

**Example 1:**

$string_one = "this is a string";

$string_two = " $string_one within a string";

**Example 2:**

$string_one = "this is a string";

$string_two = $string_one . "concatenated with another string";

Comment: It's completely opinion based for whether it improves readability or not.  To me, either one works fine as long as you are consistent throughout the code.

Comment: Single quoted values are treated as an array of single characters, while double-quoted values are treated as a value of type String. Probably because PHP reefers to C/C++ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It should be example one (avoids the extra characters in the file)

I would prefer to go with

$string_one .= "concatenated with another string";

Answer (score 0):

Its your personal choice

You can use echo `"hello $name";   *remember to use double quotes so that PHP can refer it to as a variable*`

In case of concatenation you can use comma as well:

```
echo "Welcome ", $name; *Although it works only with echo*
```